# Stretching select list 100%, aligned left with other content

Tags: html, css

I want the "Hi" div to be 20px wide and float exactly left of the select list. I want the select list to take up the remaining width.

```
<div style="overflow:auto;width:100%;">
    <div style="float:left;width:20px;">
        Hi
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <select style="width:100%">
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width:calc(100% - 20px);` in the 2nd `div` and `select` tags. You can also get rid of the `float:left` in the 2nd div.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpLjKx